# Trying to insert to database with methods from MainActivity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

im newbie with fragment, and i want to insert some data into database from Fragment with methods from MainActivity

here is my code
**LaporanFragment**

```
public class LaporanFragment extends Fragment{

EditText judulL, isiL;
TextView nomor_ktp, ambilNama;
ImageView fotoL;
Button kirim;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_laporan, container, false);

    judulL = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.judulLaporan);
    isiL = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.isiLaporan);

    nomor_ktp = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nomor_ktp);
    final String noktp = nomor_ktp.getText().toString();
    //fotoL = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foto_laporan);

    final String jdlLaporan = judulL.getText().toString();
    final String isiLaporan = isiL.getText().toString();

    kirim = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.kirim_laporan);

    kirim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).kirim_lapor(jdlLaporan, isiLaporan, noktp);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

and **MainActivity** with kirim_lapor method

```
public void kirim_lapor(final String judul, final String isi, final String username){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_LAPOR,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response){
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Toast.makeText(LaporanFragment.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    //progressDialog.hide();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("judul_laporan", judul);
            params.put("isi_laporan", isi);
            params.put("no_ktp", username);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

the problem is when i press **button** **kirim** in fragment, the app will crash
please help me guys, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: put your stacktrace with the exception here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To localize and hinder further error, instead of calling the MainActivity method via casting the `getActivity()`, you should make a **Listener** for telling the Activity about the data.

Create the interface for Listener in Fragment:

```
public class LaporanFragment extends Fragment {

  private LaporanListener mListener;

  // Define a Listener to 'speak up' to the main activity
  public interface LaporanListener {
      public void onSendReportClicked(String title, String content, String idNumber);
   }
  ...
}
```

When clicking the button sendReport, use the listener:

```
public class LaporanFragment extends Fragment {

  ...
  ...
  kirim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
           mListener.onSendReportClicked(jdlLaporan, isiLaporan, noktp);
         }
  });
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then you need to implement the interface Listener to the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LaporanFragment.LaporanListener {

   ...

   @Override
   public void onSendReportClicked(String title, String content, String idNumber) {
     // MainActivity will receive the data here.
     // You need to process here.
   }

  ...
}
```

For further reading, read [Creating Custom Listeners](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners).

Comment: when i trying to click button the app is still crash, it says : 
`E/AndroidRuntime(24882): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24882): Process: com.example.banifahlevi.mediajenggala, PID: 24882
E/AndroidRuntime(24882): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.banifahlevi.mediajenggala.LaporanFragment$LaporanListener.onSendReportClicked(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(24882):  at com.example.banifahlevi.mediajenggala.LaporanFragment$1.onClick(LaporanFragment.java:70)`

Comment: what is the code in line 70 in the error `com.example.banifahlevi.mediajenggala.LaporanFragment$1.onCl‌​ick(LaporanFragment.‌​java:70)`?, Have you implemented the interface in Activity? Did the fragment is added to the Activity?

Comment: the code is 
`mListener.onSendReportClicked(jdlLaporan, isiLaporan, noktp);`  . 
yes i did implemented interface in Activity and added to Activity

Comment: Check this line `nomor_ktp = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nomor_ktp);`, change it to `nomor_ktp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nomor_ktp);`